# Safe Callback Provider (SFINAE, std::forward and overload resolution)

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, sfinae, perfect-forwarding

I'm working on a mechanism for creating "safe" callbacks, that won't cause undefined behavior when called after their parent object has been destroyed. The class should be generic enough to be able to wrap any callback, with void(...) callbacks simply being executed or not, depending on the status of the object that they are bound to, and callbacks that return a value returning a boost::optional with the returned value, if executed, or boost::none if not executed.The implementation is almost complete, but there are 2 things that make me worried that I don't fully understand my code...

If line 19 is uncommented and 18 commented out, the template won't compile - is this merely a syntactic problem that can be solved, or am I trying to use the result_of mechanism incorrectly (does the std::forward there change the semantics or is it superfluous?)

If line 88 is uncommented and 89 commented out, the compilation results in failure due to ambiguousness of the function call to fun, which I don't quite understand - it seems to me that fun(int&&) is an exact match, so why does the compiler complain of ambiguousness with fun(int) version?

If there are other subtle (or gross) errors, please comment as well.

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

template<class Func>
class SafeCallback
{
public:
    SafeCallback(std::shared_ptr<bool> guard, const Func& callback)
        : guard_(guard)
        , callback_(callback)
    {}

    template<class... Args>
    // auto operator()(Args&&... args) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<typename std::result_of<Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...)>::type>::value,  //  won't compile with: 19:91: error: invalid use of template-name 'std::result_of' without an argument list
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type>::value,
                                                               void>::type
    {
        std::cout << "trying void callback" << std::endl;
        if(guard_.lock())
        {
            std::cout << "callback is still alive :)" << std::endl;
            callback_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            return;
        }
        std::cout << "uh-oh, callback is dead!" << std::endl;
    }

    template<class... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type>::value,
                                                               boost::optional<typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type>>::type
    {
        std::cout << "trying non-void callback" << std::endl;
        if(guard_.lock())
        {
            std::cout << "callback is still alive :)" << std::endl;
            return callback_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        std::cout << "uh-oh, callback is dead!" << std::endl;
        return boost::none;
    }

    bool isAlive()
    {
        return guard_.lock();
    }

private:  
    std::weak_ptr<bool> guard_;
    Func callback_;
};

class SafeCallbackProvider
{
public:
    SafeCallbackProvider()
        : guard_(new bool(true))
    {}

    virtual ~SafeCallbackProvider() = default;

    template<class Func>
    SafeCallback<Func> makeSafeCallback(const Func& callback)
    {
        return SafeCallback<Func>(guard_, callback);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<bool> guard_;
};

struct A : SafeCallbackProvider
{
    void fun()
    {
        std::cout << "---this is fun---" << std::endl;
    }

    int fun(int&& i)
    {
        std::cout << "&& this is && " << i << " && fun &&" << std::endl;
        return i;
    }

    // int fun(int i) // fails to compile with: 123:48: error: call of overloaded 'fun(int)' is ambiguous
    int fun(int& i)
    {
        std::cout << "---this is ---" << i << "--- fun---" << std::endl;
        return i;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* a= new A;
    auto cb = a->makeSafeCallback(
        [&]()
        {
            a->fun();
        });
    cb();
    delete a;
    cb();

    std::cout << "\n----------\n\n";

    A* a2= new A;
    auto cb2 = a2->makeSafeCallback(
        [&](int i)
        {
            return a2->fun(i);
        });
    cb2(5);
    delete a2;
    cb2(5);

    std::cout << "\n----------\n\n";

    A* a3= new A;
    auto cb3 = a3->makeSafeCallback(
        [&](int&& i)
        {
            return a3->fun(std::forward<int>(i));
        });
    cb3(5);
    delete a3;
    cb3(5);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** this only answers the first question, because I apparently have the attention span of a fly. More coming soon.

---

`std::result_of` essentially performs some magic based on a function *type* that looks like a function *call*. In the line that works:

```
typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type
```

This is the intended use, simulating the call of an instance of `Func` with values of types `Args...`. On the other hand:

```
typename std::result_of<Func(std::forward<Args>(args)...)>::type
```

This expands `Args` and `args` into a group of *values*, which then form a chain of `,`-operators inside a functoin-style cast to `Func`. The whole thing is an expression instead of the type `std::result_of` expects.

It looks like you're halfway to using `decltype` instead, which would look like:

```
decltype(std::declval<Func&>()(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
```

... or, if you can be bothered to move it underneath `callback_`'s declaration:

```
decltype(callback_(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using decltype, but I couldn't get the syntax to be as concise as Yours - the best I came up with was decltype(std::declval<Func>().operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) , it didn't occur to me that "...operator()..." part was unnecessary ;), but even so, the result_of syntax is more concise and gets the job done so I'll stick with it. I think what confused with the forwarding was the fact that decltype(declval<>()) syntax uses std::forward and I wasn't sure if result_of without forwarding would be semantically equivalent, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Rules of Overloading are that .

Signature of function should be different.

In both the case compiler is finding same signature, try to change the signature and see the result.